# How does this equal 105 instead of 15?

Tags: java, string, string-concatenation, addition

```
public class Review {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int x = 10, y = 5;
    System.out.println(" " + x + y); // string + x + y
  }

}
```

How does this equal 105 rather then 15?
What makes it different from the below code?

```
public class Review {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int x = 10, y = 5;
    System.out.println(x + y); //Only x + y
  }

}
```

Comment: Addition associates from left to right; and a String plus an int gives a String.

Comment: By the fact that you tagged this with `string-concatentation`, it seems you understand what's happening. What's really your question?

Comment: Consider the difference in `System.out.println(" " + (x + y)); `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`" " + x + y` means `" " + x` then `+ y`
so the first code that you write we can divide into 2 steps:
1. `" " + x` => `" " + 10` => `"10"`
2. `"10" + y` => `"10" + 5` => `"105"`

But the second is just a `number + number`, so we get the number result.

I'm not a native English speaker, and I'm learning, sorry about my bad English, And I hope this is helpful.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This was explained in a way that was easy to understand. Great English so don't stress it!

Answer (score 0):

The first answer the type is String because of the " " and you are using string concatenation by using the +

With the second one, the + is not being used to concatenate with a String.

Answer (score 0):

When you mix a primitive data type with a String in `System.out.println()`, the Java compiler assumes that you want every data type to be converted to a String object. Adding brackets around your primitive data types allows you to calculate first before conversion as [Jim Garrison](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18157/jim-garrison) suggested: `System.out.println(" " + (x + y));`